# Error LNK1104 linking .dll to test application in Visual Studio "invalid or corrupt file"

Tags: c++, dll, linker, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to make a simple HelloWorld DLL in C++ to get a hang of using C++ DLLs for the first time. But when I try to build my project containing my method, I always get the error `error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2B8    C:\Users\octavio\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UseOfDll\UseOfDll\HelloWorldDll.dll`.

In my `UseOfDll` project I added `C:\Users\octavio\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UseOfDll\UseOfDll\HelloWorldDll.dll` to `Project > UseOfDll Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependecies`. I also added `HelloWorldDll.dll` and `HelloDll.h` to the `UseOfDll` project directory.

This is the main method of the program (called `UseOfDll`) that utilizes the DLL:

```
// UseOfDll.cpp ----------------------------------------------------

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HelloDll.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    HelloDll helloDll;
    helloDll.hello();
    HelloDll::helloStatic();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

In my separate Visual Studio project for the DLL I have:

```
// HelloDll.h ------------------------------------------------------

#pragma once

#ifdef DLLDIR_EX
    #define DLLDIR  __declspec(dllexport)   // export DLL information
#else
    #define DLLDIR  __declspec(dllimport)   // import DLL information
#endif 

class HelloDll {
    public:
        HelloDll();
        ~HelloDll();
        void hello();
        static void helloStatic();
};

// HelloDll.cpp ----------------------------------------------------

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HelloDll.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

HelloDll::HelloDll() {}


HelloDll::~HelloDll() {}

void HelloDll::hello() {
    cout << "Hello World of DLL" << endl;
}

void HelloDll::helloStatic() {
    cout << "Hello World of DLL static" << endl;
}
```

Comment: It is a standard mistake, you cannot link a DLL.  It doesn't have enough information to let the linker do the proper job.  The linker just falls over when it can't comprehend the content of the file.  You *must* link the DLL's import library instead.

Comment: Your class is not exported, put __declspec(dllexport) on your class definition

Comment: @Matt Don't I have that already in the line after `#ifdef DLLDIR_EX`?

Comment: @roscioli, no, that is just a macro definition.

Comment: @HansPassant Is the import library the `.lib` file? And should I add the `.lib` file to **Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies** only not the `.dll` file)? Finally, when I compile my DLL project I do not get a `.lib` file. Am I configuring something incorrectly?

Comment: You don't get a .lib file because you didn't export anything.

Comment: @Matt Which class file do I put `__declspec(dllexport)` and where?

Comment: @roscioli http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Solution: replace `class HelloDll` with `class DLLDIR HelloDll`.
This links the class to the DLL export library.